using 120v Generator to power 240v deep well pump
I have a 4500 watt generator that doesn't have 240V but it has a 30 amp plug. Can I power my 240V deep well pump with this generator?

Does the well pump need 120v or 240v?  If 240v then no.  If 120 volts then maybe.  I have run my pump with a little 1000 watt honda generator with no problem.  Got a big 5000 watt generator and had problems.

Yeah it is a v240 well pump

What type of plug is this? If it has a TT-30 you're out of luck. If it has anything else it might be doable.

There exist 120-to-240 step-up transformers. But we'd need to know more electrical specs of the generator and the pump to have any hope of determining what sort of transformer might be sufficient for the job.

a 1hp 240 well pump is around 10A which is 2400 watt, so yes a 4500w [120v] generator is likely able to power a ~2400w well pump, if my assumption of your well pump is close to correct; of course if the make/model of well pump was stated then a pretty solid answer can be given.

regarding 120v only generator, at 4500 watt, what make/model is the generator; if you're not mistaken about only having 120v from the generator then you need a 120v - to -240v transformer that can accommodate the wattage of the pump, including pump startup current within reason.

and, can't believe I'm saying this,  maybe an inline GFCI on the extension cord going to the pump, depending how you are plan on wiring (hacking) things in.

The problem:
The generator only puts out 120Vac, and the pump needs 240Vac. The pump would only run at quarter-power (when volts are halved, current goes half too, for the same load). It might bring some water up (might), but it will likely not pressurize the well tank to normal amounts. It may not spin enough to get water up out of the deep pipe. It may not start spinning at all, remaining locked-rotor because of not enough power input, and become a water heater in the well before it self-destructs.
Also, the startup current requirements are often much more than the running amps. My well pump has 6-ish running amps and 26 start amps at 240V. (That's ~1500 watts run and 6200 watts start.) Your pump probably has similar startup current draw. If the pump rotor remains locked-rotor or runs slow, the draw may be too much for your generator.
It is possible to use a suitable-size transformer to make 120V into 240V. But that will double the current draw on the generator, aside from losses from the transformer itself. (Example, my well pump would draw 12 amps running and 52 amps starting through a 120V-240V transformer, and add a bit more amps for the losses. That 52-amp draw might trip a 30-amp breaker.)
A possibility:
All that said, it could be worth it to try a quick experiment. If you disconnect the well from the pressurized house plumbing system, so the pump pipe output feeds directly to free air, not the house plumbing, and try starting the pump with the 30-amp 120V output, it might get water up the pipe, perhaps enough to fill a clean pail or two to take into the house.
The generator will likely bog down some at the start. If it bogs down almost or all the way to stopping or trips its breaker, then experiment done. No, the genny will not run the pump.
If the genny stays running but you get only a trickle out of the free-air pipe, then the pump cannot handle getting water out of the well at 120V. Experiment done. No, the genny will not run the pump well enough.
If you get decent enough water flow to fill a 3 to 5 gallon bucket in a minute, then it may serve as a temporary system, not run regularly so the pump doesn't overheat, and may get you through the need.
If you get a fire hose' worth of water from the free-air pipe, then that's even better, but I would still not connect the pressurized system back up. The pump would still be running quarter power, and that would be bad somehow in the long run.
If you need a full regular house setup, get a 240V generator.
Keep in mind that water and electricity don't mix (or do they actually mix too well?). Be careful doing the experiment with the well's electrical connections, and keep the electricity isolated from the water output. Only run the experiment once if the generator bogs to a stop or trips, or if the bucket takes more than a minute to fill; these failures mean the pump is being abused.

You're correct about Ohms law, but usually when V is reduced I is reduced too. It ends up being roughly a square-law relationship: power is proportional to the voltage squared so a drop from 240 to 120 yields 1/4 the power. But this pump may be an induction motor. In that case it's likely not to even start and it's at high risk of being damaged when powered with such a severe under-voltage condition. info at electronics.se

Thanks, @GregHill, that was digging in the back of my mind, too, 1/2 or 1/4. I forgot that the current would drop too.

My 5000w generator would blow its breakers trying to run my pump on regular sized wire gauge.  Did get it running by going to 10 gauge short run of cable from the gen.  Pump(120v) was on a 15 amp house circuit.  Pump was disconnected from the house circuit if on gen.
